# On which event should I remove the view?

Tags: iphone, ios, events, uiview

I am loading a view(similar to the mapview annotation) on the click of an image. I need to remove the annotation view when I click on any other place in the view. On which event should I remove the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`  to remove the view.